# How to disable button based on a condition in a R Markdown document with shiny elements?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinyjs

Suppose we have a group of 8 checkboxes (8 letters) and an action button which prints the label of all the selected checkboxes. What I want to do, enable and disable the state of the action button based on a condition. The condition is that if the number of selected checkboxes are between 2 and 5, then the button should be enabled, else disabled. For changing the state of the button I want to use the functions `enable`, `disable` or `toggleState` functions from the `shinyjs` package. And when the button is enabled, I will be able to trigger an event to print the numbers of selected items.
Here is what I tried until now:

````
---
title: "Disable Button"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
checkboxGroupInput("param_group", label = h3("Letters"), 
    choices = LETTERS[1:8])

actionButton('action', "Print")

result<-reactive({
  length(input$param_group)
})

observe({
  if(result()>1 & result()<=5)
    enable("action")
  else
    disable("action")
})

txt<-eventReactive(input$action,{
    cat("Number of letters selected: ",length(input$param_group))
})

renderPrint({
  txt()
})
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me awhile to find it, but you have to enable `shinyjs` to use R-markdown explicitly, it needs to setup its javascript differently in this case.

You do this by calling: `useShinyjs(rmd=T)` in the chunk where you are using it.

````
---
title: "Disable Button"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
useShinyjs(rmd=T)

checkboxGroupInput("param_group", label = h3("Letters"), 
                   choices = LETTERS[1:8])

actionButton('action', "Print")


result<-reactive({
  length(input$param_group)
})

observe({
  useShinyjs()
  if(result()>1 & result()<=5){
    enable("action")
  } else {
    disable("action")
  }
})

txt<-eventReactive(input$action,{
  cat("Number of letters selected: ",length(input$param_group))
})

renderPrint({
  txt()
})
````

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Yes unfortunately that `rmd=TRUE` is required and cannot be done automatically because I was not able to find a reliable way to know whether it's called from a shiny app or from an Rmd, since there is a very thin line between them. I asked rstudio about this and they couldn't find a proper solution either, but that was 2 years ago. If you have an idea how this could be done I'm open to suggestions :)